# Plugin to generate call case

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is there any easy and good plugin for Eclipse to generate UML and plugin to get call diagram from code Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MaintainJ](http://www.maintainj.com/index.html) will generate UML sequence diagrams.

So will [OMONDO](http://www.ejb3.org/).

You can find other plugins that will do it using Google and a little poking around.  The key is that "sequence diagram" is the name of the UML diagram that illustrates how objects call each other.